# Logging opentelemetry tracid in spring boot reactive server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller, open-telemetry

I am developing a java rest api server with spring boot 3 based on spring-boot-starter-webflux.

How to integrate opentelemetry traceid so that each log line contains the traceid?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your choice of instrumentation.
If you're using the [java agent](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation), you don't need to include any dependencies, you can use `thread_id` and `span_id` directly to configure your logger, such as in this log4j example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout
          pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} trace_id=%X{trace_id} span_id=%X{span_id} trace_flags=%X{trace_flags} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root>
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="All"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you're not using the java agent, you need to include a library that injects the span and trace ID into the context or MDC object.
Other than that, it works as in the example above.

- For log4j, use [opentelemetry-log4j-context-data-2.17-autoconfigure](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/log4j/log4j-context-data/log4j-context-data-2.17/library-autoconfigure/README.md)
- For logback, use [opentelemetry-logback-mdc-1.0](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-mdc-1.0/library/README.md)

Note that it's also possible to send logs to an OpenTelemetry backend using the OTLP protocol. Technically this means adding a different appender independent from the console appender. This appender will transmit the span and trace ID separately from the message body (as attributes).

- If you're using the java agent, this appender is automatically added for you.
- If you're not using the java agent, you can find a full example in the [grafana OpenTelemetry starter](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter) (full disclosure: I'm the author of this starter).