# What is the difference between using OpenTelemetry agent vs adding opentelemetry-exporter-otlp in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, open-telemetry

The official OpenTelemetry docs encourage using the Java agent to instrument applications.

The Spring boot docs don't mention the agent, and they say they autoconfigure OTLP when the `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel` and `io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp`.

I'm trying to understand which approach to use: Is the agent also required for Spring Boot? Without the agent will Spring Boot respect the standard environment variables for configuring OTEL? Will Spring Boot also configure OTel agent features such as injecting MDC logging with span and trace IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing, I would also agree recommend the Java agent for most use cases - it's easier to set up and supports more libraries than spring boot alone does (this may change in the future, the OpenTelemetry support in Spring has just been added in Spring Boot 3).

When should you use spring's native OpenTelemetry support?

- You use Spring Boot 3+
- You want to avoid the startup time of the Java agent, e.g. when you use FaaS (function as a service)
- You want to use a native image

> Is the agent also required for Spring Boot?

No, you can use Spring boot without the java agent - an example can be found in the [Grafana OpenTelemetry starter](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter) (full disclosure: I'm the author).

> Without the agent will Spring Boot respect the standard environment variables for configuring OTEL?

The most important standard environment variables are supported - but not all.

> Will Spring Boot also configure OTel agent features such as injecting MDC logging with span and trace IDs?

No, but you can configure this by adding an additional dependency - see [Logging opentelemetry tracid in spring boot reactive server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555166/logging-opentelemetry-tracid-in-spring-boot-reactive-server)